# JQGrid export using SelectPDF, no data in linked JQGrid

Tags: asp.net, pdf, jqgrid, export, htmltextwriter

I have 2 JQGrids on my ASPX page. When an Invoice is selected on the top grid, it loads the corresponding data on the second.

My issue is with exporting. When I export the page using SelectPDF, the 2nd Grid View is always empty.

Here is what it looks like on the page:

[image]

...and this is what the exported PDF looks like, there is no data in the second grid.

[image]

Here is the ASPX code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Invoicing" Codebehind="Invoicing.aspx.cs" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Trirand.Web" TagPrefix="trirand" Namespace="Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<link href="themes/CustomStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/trirand/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/trirand/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Indigo2.Properties.Settings.Constr %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT [invoice_number],[invoice_date],[custid],[inv_splitter] FROM [Indigo].[dbo].[invoices]" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"
UpdateCommand=""
DeleteCommand="">
    <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="invoice_number" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="invoice_date" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="custid" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="inv_splitter" Type="String" />
     </UpdateParameters>    
     <DeleteParameters>
     </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Indigo2.Properties.Settings.Constr %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT [inv_item_id],[description],[unit_sell],[qty],[inv_section],[inv_orderby],[inv_splitter],[ref_date_start],[ref_date_end],[custid],[cust_po],[invoice_number], unit_sell * qty as Price FROM [Indigo].[dbo].[invoice_items] WHERE (invoice_number = @invoice_number) " CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"
UpdateCommand="UPDATE Invoice_items SET cust_po=@cust_po, description=@description, ref_date_start=CONVERT(datetime, @ref_date_start, 105), ref_date_end=CONVERT(datetime, @ref_date_end, 105), unit_sell=@unit_sell, qty=@qty WHERE inv_item_id=@inv_item_id"
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Invoice_items WHERE inv_item_id=@inv_item_id">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="invoice_number" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="inv_item_id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="cust_po" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ref_date_start" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ref_date_end" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="unit_sell" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="qty" Type="Int32" />
     </UpdateParameters>    
     <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="inv_item_id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="cust_po" Type="String" />
     </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <br />
        <trirand:JQGrid runat="server" ID="JQGrid1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="1200"
            OnRowSelecting="JQGrid1_RowSelecting">
            <Columns>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="invoice_number" HeaderText="ID" PrimaryKey="True" Width="100" />
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="invoice_date" Editable="true" DataFormatString="{0:d}" Width="100"/>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="custid" Editable="true" Width="100"/>
            </Columns>
            <ToolBarSettings ShowEditButton="true" ShowRefreshButton="True" ShowAddButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowSearchButton="True" />
        </trirand:JQGrid>
        <br />
        <trirand:JQGrid runat="server" ID="JQGrid2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" Width="1200" Height="100%" maxHeight="300" hidegrid="true" ondatarequested="JQGrid2_DataRequested">
            <Columns>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn CSSClass="indent" DataField="description" Editable="true" Width="800"/>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="inv_section" Editable="true" />
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="ref_date_start" Editable="true" DataFormatString="{0:d}" Width="200"/>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="ref_date_end" Editable="true" DataFormatString="{0:d}" Width="200"/>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="cust_po" Editable="true" />
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="unit_sell" Editable="true" DataFormatString="{0:c}" Width="200"/>  
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="qty" Editable="true" Width="200"/>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="price" Editable="false" DataFormatString="{0:c}" Width="200" >
        </trirand:JQGridColumn> 

            </Columns>
            <PagerSettings PageSize="12" />        
            <GroupSettings CollapseGroups="false">
                <GroupFields>
                    <trirand:GroupField 
                        DataField="inv_section"
                        HeaderText="<b>{0}</b>" 
                        GroupSortDirection="Asc"
                        ShowGroupColumn="false"
                        ShowGroupSummary="true"/>    
                    <trirand:GroupField 
                        DataField="cust_po"
                        HeaderText="PO Reference: &lt;b&gt;{0}&lt;/b&gt" 
                        GroupSortDirection="Asc"
                        ShowGroupColumn="false"
                        ShowGroupSummary="false"/>
                </GroupFields>
            </GroupSettings>
            <AppearanceSettings ShowFooter="true" />
            <ToolBarSettings ShowEditButton="true" ShowRefreshButton="True" ShowAddButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowSearchButton="True" />
        </trirand:JQGrid>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="ExportToPDFButton" Text="Export to PDF" OnClick="BtnCreatePdf_Click" />
```

...and here is the underlying code

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using SelectPdf;
using System.Web;

public partial class Invoicing : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    JQGrid2.Visible = true; //was false!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    if (Session["invoice_number"] != null)
    {
        JQGrid2.Visible = true;
        SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["invoice_number"].DefaultValue = Session["invoice_number"] as string;
    }
}

protected void JQGrid2_DataRequested(object sender, Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls.JQGridDataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = e.DataTable; // get only the current page data            

    double poTotal = 0;

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        double poValue = (double)row["price"];
        poTotal += poValue;
    }

    string formattedMoneyValue = String.Format("{0:C}", poTotal);

    JQGrid2.Columns.FromDataField("price").FooterValue = formattedMoneyValue.ToString();
    JQGrid2.Columns.FromDataField("qty").FooterValue = "Total:";
}

protected void JQGrid1_RowSelecting(object sender, Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls.JQGridRowSelectEventArgs e)
{
    Session["invoice_number"] = JQGrid1.SelectedRow;

    JQGrid2.Visible = true;
    SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["invoice_number"].DefaultValue = Session["invoice_number"] as string;
}

//Start of Select PDF Code//
    private bool startConversion = false;

    protected void BtnCreatePdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        startConversion = true;
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (startConversion)
        {

        Session["invoice_number"] = JQGrid1.SelectedRow;

        JQGrid2.Visible = true;
        SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["invoice_number"].DefaultValue = Session["invoice_number"] as string;

        // get html of the page 
        TextWriter myWriter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(myWriter);
            base.Render(htmlWriter);

            // instantiate a html to pdf converter object 
            HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();

            // create a new pdf document converting the html string of the page 
            PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(
                myWriter.ToString(), Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

        // save pdf document 
        doc.Save(Response, false, "Sample.pdf");

            // close pdf document 
            doc.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            // render web page in browser 
            base.Render(writer);
        }
    }

}
```

Please can someone help me, with what I need to do so that the data from the second grid is passed to the PDF when exported.

**UPDATE:**
If I hardcode the default value for the datasource on the second grid it exports the correct info.

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1000" Name="invoice_number" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
```

For some reason when I export, it seems to be clearing this parameter value, if I set it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The SelectPdf convert loads your web page using a new Session, so it does not know your dynamically set parameters. You need to send them in the url, if possible.

Comment: The highlighted row for ID 1005 means this is not a completely new session. Some session information must have been passed for it to have highlighted the selected row.